# Disable and redirect pagination of Home

Tags: pagination, homepage

My home is a static page, but Wordpress create enumeration "home/page/2/.../3/" and the only solution found that disable pages generation, also redirecting, is the instruction below, but I would like it to have effect only the home page and not the whole site.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

```
global $posts, $numpages;

$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$result = preg_match('%\/(\d)+(\/)?$%', $request_uri, $matches);

$ordinal = $result ? intval($matches[1]) : FALSE;

if(is_numeric($ordinal)) {

    setup_postdata($posts[0]);

    $redirect_to = ($ordinal < 2) ? '/': (($ordinal > $numpages) ? "/$numpages/" : FALSE);

    if(is_string($redirect_to)) {

        $redirect_url = get_option('home') . preg_replace('%'.$matches[0].'%', $redirect_to, $request_uri);

        if($ordinal < 2) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
        } else {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 302 Found');
        }

        header("Location: $redirect_url");
        exit();

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say your home is a static page, do you mean page in WP Admin that you've chosen in the settings screen to replace the homepage? a `home.php` template in your theme? a static `index.html` file in the root folder of your website? A `frontpage.php` template in your theme? Or something else?

Comment: Hi, I mean in settings screen of WP, otherwise the theme uses page.php and category.php.

Comment: I've this on page, where “publisher” is theme's name: $layout_setting = publisher_get_page_layout_setting();

if ( ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) && is_front_page() && bf_get_query_var_paged( 1 ) > 1 ) {
 $content_type = 'front paginated';
} elseif ( publisher_is_singular() ) {
 $content_type = 'singular';
} // Other pages template
else {
 $content_type = 'archive';
}

Comment: How do you know about these pages? Are you seeing pagination at the bottom of the homepage?

Comment: @TomJNowell, I can see pagination at bottom from second page of the Home, writing url: http://namesite/page/2/....and then /page/3/ and forward.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean only on the first page?

If so, you need that if statement:

```
if ( !is_paged() ) {
//do stuff only on 1 page
}
```

If it's not working probably you should create a new variable that will store your home page URL and make another if statement like, if URL is `https://yourdomain.com/` then do stuff.

Comment: I don't know if I'm putting the instruction in the correct place, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from a string found in the theme files, I trivially added the following instruction in the function file:

`function no_pagination_home() {
$paged = bf_get_query_var_paged();
if ( is_home() || ( ( 'page' === get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) && is_front_page() && bf_get_query_var_paged( 1 ) > 1 )) {
header("Location: home");
exit();
}
}
add_action ('parse_query', 'no_pagination_home');`

It does exactly what I was looking for, i.e. it avoids the pagination of Home only by forcing the redirection to it, leaving it in the categories, but with PHP 8, warnings appear on the header which I cannot explain:

**Warning**: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /class-wp-query.php  on line 4044

**Warning**: Attempt to read property "post-title" on null in /class-wp-query.php  on line 4066

**Warning**: Attempt to read property "post-name" on null in /class-wp-query.php  on line 4048

And the strings involved are:

```
public function is_page( $page = '' ) {
    if ( ! $this->is_page ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( empty( $page ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    $page_obj = $this->get_queried_object();

    $page = array_map( 'strval', (array) $page );

    if ( in_array( (string) $page_obj->ID, $page, true ) ) {
        return true;
    } elseif ( in_array( $page_obj->post_title, $page, true ) ) {
        return true;
    } elseif ( in_array( $page_obj->post_name, $page, true ) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        foreach ( $page as $pagepath ) {
            if ( ! strpos( $pagepath, '/' ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $pagepath_obj = get_page_by_path( $pagepath );

            if ( $pagepath_obj && ( $pagepath_obj->ID == $page_obj->ID ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```